# Laravel - Save Guzzle JSON response to Database

Tags: php, json, database, laravel, guzzle

I am using Guzzle to access an external API:

```
$api = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://www.space-track.org',
    'cookies' => true, 
]);
$api->post('ajaxauth/login', [
     'form_params' => [
         'identity' => 'myidentity', 
         'password' => 'mypassword', 
      ],
]);
$response = $api->get('basicspacedata/query/class/boxscore/format/json');
return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
$api->get('ajaxauth/logout');
dd($boxscore);
```

With this I am able to access the API and display the JSON file on my webpage. Instead of doing this, what I want to do is to save the JSON result into my database and then display it from my own database.

I am able to seed a local JSON file, but I am unable to save the Guzzle result.

Is there anyway to save a Guzzle response JSON file into my database?

**EDIT:**
Here is the model and migration for the database:

*Migration*

```
 Schema::create('operators', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('COUNTRY');
     $table->string('SPADOC_CD');
     $table->string('ORBITAL_TBA');
     $table->string('ORBITAL_PAYLOAD_COUNT');
     $table->string('ORBITAL_ROCKET_BODY_COUNT');
     $table->string('ORBITAL_DEBRIS_COUNT');
     $table->string('ORBITAL_TOTAL_COUNT');
     $table->string('DECAYED_PAYLOAD_COUNT');
     $table->string('DECAYED_ROCKET_BODY_COUNT');
     $table->string('DECAYED_DEBRIS_COUNT');
     $table->string('DECAYED_TOTAL_COUNT');
     $table->string('COUNTRY_TOTAL');
 });
```

*Model*

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'COUNTRY',
    'SPADOC_CD',
    'ORBITAL_TBA',
    'ORBITAL_PAYLOAD_COUNT',
    'ORBITAL_ROCKET_BODY_COUNT',
    'ORBITAL_DEBRIS_COUNT',
    'ORBITAL_TOTAL_COUNT',
    'DECAYED_PAYLOAD_COUNT',
    'DECAYED_ROCKET_BODY_COUNT',
    'DECAYED_DEBRIS_COUNT',
    'DECAYED_TOTAL_COUNT',
    'COUNTRY_TOTAL'
];
```

**EDIT 2:**
I have received some help in regards to this question. I am able to create a model that mirrors the database:

```
$api = new Client([
'base_uri' => 'https://www.space-track.org',
'cookies' => true, 
 ]); $api->post('ajaxauth/login', [
      'form_params' => [
         'identity' => 'myidentity', 
         'password' => 'mypassword', 
     ],
 ]);
 $response = $api-get('basicspacedata/query/class/boxscore/format/json');
  $mydata = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
  $object = new Object();
  $object->COUNTRY = $mydata->COUNTRY;
  $object->SPADOC_CD = $mydata->SPADOC_CD
  $object->save();
return redirect('your/url',compact('object'));
```

This pulls the data from the database, but does not save it. It allows me to access the saved variable.

What I need to do is to somehow save the variable into my 'satellite' database.

TL;DR:  I simply want to save the data fetched from the API to my database

Comment: What do you mean by "to seed a Guzzle response"? Do you simply want to save the data fetched from the API to your database? If so have you created models and migrations for this data?

Comment: You’re supposed to seed data with a known dataset for local development. Seeding in your application will break if the API is not available, you don’t have an internet connection, or the API changes its response format.

Comment: @D. 777KLM No, for the reasons mentioned in previous comment. If someone’s cloned your project, then gets on a train without WiFi and tries to set up your project, it’s not going to work because the seeder won’t be able to contact the API.

Comment: @D.777KLM Yes, it’s hypothetically possible. Just saying the _intention_ of seeding is to be able to start your application with a set of known data already loaded, without any dependencies (such as a network connection). Populating a database with results from a web service goes against that.

Comment: @D.777KLM I’d download copies of the data to JSON files, store them in say **resources/assets/json/somefile.json**, and then load that file for seeding. If you application functions and your tests pass with this seed data, then it _should_ work in production with different data (but in the same schema).